# SSD crashed after Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I was running Ubuntu 22.04 on an external SSD. Everything was going good until, like an idiot, I knocked it off my desk and it unplugged. I'm signed back in to windows now but my computer will not recognize my SSD. When I plug it in it's led indicator turns blue for a moment and then it shuts off and I keep getting the "USB device not recognized" message from Windows. How do I fix this? Is the SSD totally screwed?

Comment: Almost all drives (*internal & external*) made within the last twenty years have SMART on them (*in the circuitry*) so ask the drive for its health - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools   If you don't get a response from the chips (SMART) you won't be able to access the actual drive itself (be it SSD or HDD)  FYI:  If not obvious, I'd run this from *live* media (eg. Ubuntu on thumb-drive), windows support isn't on-topic here